# For loop from DictReader not iterating all fieldnames

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, openpyxl

I am trying to load a csv[what CSV looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iekuJ.png) file into a dictionary, convert the excel dates to ISO timestamp and retrieve the values based on the header. I get no error but my for loop parses only the first header.
At the end of this post you will find a datasample should you need it.

```
import csv
from openpyxl.utils.datetime import from_excel, to_ISO8601

#Capturing the headers in a list
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("file.csv"))
for i in range(4,9):
    print(headers[i])
    for row in vehicle_list:
        x = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value = float(row[str(headers[i])])))
        print(x)
```

The result is:

```
Engineon
2019-12-16T01:57:08Z
2019-12-16T02:08:42Z
2019-12-16T02:31:44Z
2019-12-16T02:45:41Z
2019-12-16T02:45:41Z
2019-12-16T03:02:57Z
2019-12-16T03:02:57Z
2019-12-16T03:31:37Z
2019-12-16T17:31:05Z
2019-12-16T17:54:54Z
2019-12-16T17:54:54Z
2019-12-16T18:23:04Z
2019-12-16T18:23:04Z
2019-12-16T19:03:48Z
2019-12-16T19:18:13Z
2019-12-16T20:02:56Z
2019-12-16T20:34:46Z
2019-12-16T20:51:35Z
2019-12-16T21:00:01Z
2019-12-16T21:15:06Z
2019-12-16T21:15:06Z
2019-12-16T21:55:33Z
2019-12-16T22:12:13Z
Engineoff
WorkStart
WorkEnd
ParkStart
```

So basically it ran only for "Engineon" header and not for the rest

Sample data:

```
vehicle_list = [('85807835', [{'ID': '85807835', 'Vhcl': 'V001', 'Mode': 'Manual', 'CID': 'AAA5846129341',
'Engineon': '43815.08135','Engineoff': '43815.08938', 'WorkStart': '', 'WorkEnd': '', 'ParkStart': '43815.07334',
'ParkEnd': '43815.08211'}]), ('85809668', [{'ID': '85809668', 'Vhcl': 'V002', 'Mode': 'Auto',
'CID': 'AAA8022407504', 'Engineon': '43815.08938', 'Engineoff': '43815.10535', 'WorkStart': '43815.08938',
'WorkEnd': '43815.10535', 'ParkStart': '43815.08938', 'ParkEnd': '43815.09535'}]), ('85810976', [{'ID': '85810976',
'Vhcl': 'V003', 'Mode': 'Auto', 'CID': 'AAA0571518764', 'Engineon': '43815.10538', 'Engineoff': '43815.11505',
'WorkStart': '43815.10538', 'WorkEnd': '43815.11505', 'ParkStart': '43815.10959', 'ParkEnd': '43815.11505'}]),
 ('85813025', [{'ID': '85813025', 'Vhcl': 'V004', 'Mode': 'Manual', 'CID': 'AAA3189634914', 'Engineon': '43815.11506',
'Engineoff': '43815.12703', 'WorkStart': '43815.11506', 'WorkEnd': '43815.12703', 'ParkStart': '43815.11506',
'ParkEnd': '43815.12303'}]), ('85813028', [{'ID': '85813028', 'Vhcl': 'V005', 'Mode': 'Manual', 'CID': 'AAA1940741282',
'Engineon': '43815.11506', 'Engineoff': '43815.12703', 'WorkStart': '', 'WorkEnd': '', 'ParkStart': '43815.11506',
'ParkEnd': '43815.12372'}]), ('85815305', [{'ID': '85815305', 'Vhcl': 'V006', 'Mode': 'Manual', 'CID': 'AAA1894455904',
'Engineon': '43815.12705', 'Engineoff': '43815.14505', 'WorkStart': '43815.12705', 'WorkEnd': '43815.14692',
'ParkStart': '43815.13366', 'ParkEnd': '43815.14505'}]), ('85815467', [{'ID': '85815467', 'Vhcl': 'V001',
'Mode': 'Auto', 'CID': 'AAA9538532026', 'Engineon': '43815.12705', 'Engineoff': '43815.14692', 'WorkStart': '',
'WorkEnd': '', 'ParkStart': '43815.13361', 'ParkEnd': '43815.14692'}]), ('85821410', [{'ID': '85821410',
'Vhcl': 'V002', 'Mode': 'Auto', 'CID': 'AAA8391952906', 'Engineon': '43815.14696', 'Engineoff': '43815.20984',
'WorkStart': '43815.14696', 'WorkEnd': '43815.20984', 'ParkStart': '43815.14696', 'ParkEnd': '43815.15206'}])]
```

```
ID,Vhcl,Mode,CID,Engineon,Engineoff,WorkStart,WorkEnd,ParkStart,ParkEnd
85807835,V001,Manual,AAA5846129341,43815.08135,43815.08938,,,43815.07334,43815.08211
85809668,V002,Auto,AAA8022407504,43815.08938,43815.10535,43815.08938,43815.10535,43815.08938,43815.09535
85810976,V003,Auto,AAA0571518764,43815.10538,43815.11505,43815.10538,43815.11505,43815.10959,43815.11505
85813025,V004,Manual,AAA3189634914,43815.11506,43815.12703,43815.11506,43815.12703,43815.11506,43815.12303
85813028,V005,Manual,AAA1940741282,43815.11506,43815.12703,,,43815.11506,43815.12372
85815305,V006,Manual,AAA1894455904,43815.12705,43815.14505,43815.12705,43815.14692,43815.13366,43815.14505
85815467,V001,Auto,AAA9538532026,43815.12705,43815.14692,,,43815.13361,43815.14692
85821410,V002,Auto,AAA8391952906,43815.14696,43815.20984,43815.14696,43815.20984,43815.14696,43815.15206
85873358,V003,Manual,AAA4922964611,43815.72992,43815.74645,43815.72992,43815.74645,43815.73586,43815.74645
85875020,V004,Manual,AAA6039158858,43815.74646,43815.76461,43815.74646,43815.76601,43815.75975,43815.76461
85875137,V005,Manual,AAA7495366053,43815.74646,43815.76601,,,43815.75972,43815.76601
85877825,V006,Auto,AAA7638509608,43815.76602,43815.79272,43815.76602,43815.79429,43815.76602,43815.77079
85877942,V001,Auto,AAA1265572219,43815.76602,43815.79429,,,43815.76602,43815.76985
85879040,V002,Manual,AAA2968711840,43815.79431,43815.80431,43815.79431,43815.80431,43815.79431,43815.80127
85882028,V003,Manual,AAA7692514875,43815.80432,43815.83537,43815.80432,43815.83537,43815.80432,43815.82109
85884230,V004,Manual,AAA4674654439,43815.83538,43815.85745,43815.83538,43815.85745,43815.83538,43815.84685
85885460,V005,Auto,AAA8107186366,43815.85748,43815.86895,43815.85748,43815.86895,43815.86016,43815.86895
85885994,V006,Auto,AAA5796012701,43815.86916,43815.875,43815.86916,43815.875,43815.87164,43815.875
85886981,V001,Manual,AAA8719492664,43815.87502,43815.88547,43815.87502,43815.88547,43815.8795,43815.88547
85890116,V002,Manual,AAA2865936367,43815.88549,43815.91355,43815.88549,43815.91355,43815.89722,43815.9073
85890119,V003,Manual,AAA1887612592,43815.88549,43815.91355,,,43815.88549,43815.8972
85891310,V004,Auto,AAA1144467605,43815.91358,43815.92514,43815.91358,43815.92514,43815.91856,43815.92514
85892144,V005,Auto,AAA3719694551,43815.92516,43815.93397,43815.92516,43815.93523,43815.92922,43815.93397
```

Comment: @AMC For the context manager noted, I added but no change, also i added an image of the CSV, it's practically the data i provide at the end of the post. Thanks

Comment: @Paul ***`vehicle_list`** is undefined? I assume it's the `csv.DictReader` object which is of type `generator`. Therefore you can't loop a `generator` multiple times by default.

Comment: @stovfl Indeed it is, thank you for the clarification. Is there a better way to do this?
This = load data onto a dictionary and loop through it

Comment: @Paul ***"Indeed it is"***: [Edit] your question and correct it. Change to `vehicle_list = list(csv.DictReader(...))`

Comment: `x = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value = float(row[str(headers[i])])))` looks insane. What are you actually trying to convert?

Comment: @CharlieClark I want to convert data in excel format to a DateTime format and compare it with other datetimes

Comment: openpyxl automatically converts Excel dates and times in Python datetime objects.

Comment: @CharlieClark I called from_excel and to_ISO8601 from openpyxl. Your point is that i don't need to use the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program logic is wrong here:

```
for i in range(4,9):              # runs 5 times (works)
    print(headers[i])             # prints current header name (works)
    for row in vehicle_list:      # runs the generator vehicle_list to its end (works once!)
        ...
```

The CSV reader is a generator, and generators are forward-only. It will loop through the file *one time* and will **not** reset to the start again once it has done that. For the second column, there will not be any rows left, which explains what you see in your output.

You must reverse your loops: Outer loop `for row in vehicle_list`, inner loop `for i in range(4, 9)`. This way the CSV reader only needs to loop once, but you still get to go over each column.

This is a bit better (it works like a filter, substituting the Excel date values in-place as it goes over the file):

```
def read_vehicle_data(csv_filename):
    dt_cols = ["Engineon","Engineoff","WorkStart","WorkEnd","ParkStart","ParkEnd"]

    with open(csv_filename, encoding="utf8", newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            for col in dt_cols:
                row[col] = to_ISO8601(from_excel(float(row[col])))
            yield row
```

you can call it like this:

```
for record in read_vehicle_data("file.csv"):
    print(record)
```

`range(4, 9)` is a generator as well, so it also only goes forward. But a new one is created with every row iteration - and creating a new `range(4, 9)` is *much* cheaper than opening the CSV file from scratch again, which would be necessary if you kept `range(4, 9)` as the outer loop.

Comment: thank you but it produces error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DictReader

Comment: I have tested with a CSV file called "file.csv" and the exact code shown above. If you're doing anything else, the error is in your code.